# I need an RTree implementation in Java that matches my C++ RTree library. Can the aled library work for me?

Tags: java, c++

I have to port a library package from C++ into Java (without calling JNI), and in C++ RTree.h for insert method have the following parameters:

```cpp
Insert(const ELEMTYPE a_min[NUMDIMS], const ELEMTYPE a_max[NUMDIMS], const DATATYPE& a_dataId);
```

(https://github.com/nushoin/RTree/blob/master/RTree.h)

in Java, [the RTree library implementation by aled](https://github.com/aled/jsi/blob/master/src/main/java/net/sf/jsi/rtree/RTree.java) has the method `add` with the following paramters and implementation:

```java
   public void add(Rectangle r, int id) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("Adding rectangle " + r + ", id " + id);
    }

    add(r.minX, r.minY, r.maxX, r.maxY, id, 1);

    size++;

    if (INTERNAL_CONSISTENCY_CHECKING) {
      checkConsistency();
    }
  }
```

My question is if is possible to use `add()` method from RTree Java implementation like the `insert()` method from C++ RTree.h?